# Can't get data with Ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i used JQ http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js
My ajaxpost.js

```
function a(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ("php/work/slider.php"),
        data: {id:id},
        success: function(){
        $("#"+id).load("php/work/slider.php");
        datatype:'text'
    });
}
```

There i posted my ID and load my php page in to main page

my slider.php

```
<?php 
    echo $_POST['id'];
?>
```

but i have ex. (Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/html/test/php/work/slider.php on line 2 )

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code says this:

> POST an id to `slider.php` then, if you get a successful response, make a GET request to `slider.php` and put the response in `"#"+id`.

When you make the GET request, you aren't POSTing an id.

Don't use `load`. Use the data you already have back.

```
success: function(data){
    $("#"+id).html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have following mistakes:

- You have missed `}` of success callback.
- you also have `dataType: text` after success callback.
- you will get data in success callback you can simply show it. You do not need to load again from php file.

Try this:

```
 function a(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ("php/work/slider.php"),
        data: {id:id},
        datatype:'text',
        success: function(data){
         $("#"+id).html(data);
       }


    });
}
```

ask me if you have any confusion.

Comment: but I load the file that is built my slider

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting the ID to appear in your html element then your success function is wrongly defined.

use:

```
success: function( data ){
    $("#"+id).html( data );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to load the response from the ajax page we need to do the following in the ajax page.

```
success: function(response){



           $('#test').html(response);

        }
```

Take a div in the current page and load the response from that ajax to this div.like

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Then the response will be loaded on to this div.
Hope this helps!